# Query for distinct model instances using values from a many to one table in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, django-orm

I have three models, called `Order`, `Adjustment`, and `Location`, respectively.

**My `Order` model (truncated to only show relevant fields) looks like this:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=48, primary_key=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
```

**while the `Adjustment` model looks like this:**

```
class Adjustment(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=48, primary_key=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='adjustments', null=True, default=None)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, default=None)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**and finally the `Location` model looks like this:**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, default=None)
    state_long = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default=None)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, default=None)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, default=None)
    country_long = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default=None)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, default=None)
```

---

**The code for the query in question lies here:**

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(
    adjustments__type='payment',
    adjustments__location__isnull=False,
    status__gte=200,
    status__lt=300

    ).exclude(
        adjustments__location__zipcode__in=['', '0000', '00000', 0000, 00000]
    ).values(
            # 'id',
            'adjustments__location__city',
            'adjustments__location__state',
            'adjustments__location__country'
    ).annotate(
        bookings=Count('amount'), #, distinct=True),
        total_booking_value=Sum('amount'),
        average_booking_value=Avg('amount')
    )
```

---

**Problem Statement:**

Get all distinct orders where the city, state, and country match and count the number of orders (bookings), their value, and their average value.

Currently, there are sometimes multiple adjustments of type "payment" for a single `order`, therefore duplication occurs. If I add the `id` field in as a join value, it will simply give me a single order and its `location` and revenue statistics. I can iterate over these and do my own calculations while ignoring duplication of `order.id`, but that seems like a waste of a perfectly good ORM query.

**Note:** I also tried `.distinct()` after the `.filter()` command without any effect.

Interestingly, I attempted to add `distinct=True` inside the `Count()` command, which reduced the number of orders... but the number doesn't make sense and is wrong (reduced a number from 29 to 12, but the correct number is 28 because there is one duplicated `order`).

If anyone has any suggestions, solutions, or sees any fundamental issues with my code, please let me know! I would be most grateful!

Comment: You can improve the readability of your code by joining some lines and leaving out the backslash, for example instead of: `) \  .exclude(` which is spread over 3 lines, you can do `).exclude(` in just one line. This is just my opinion as I find the backslashes somewhat annoying and almost never use them.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a repository with test data? It's hard to make a blind guess and recreating the whole project, while not having relevant data, in order to debug is too much overhead for many people willing to help.

Comment: @cezar to abide by PEP-8, you need to have lines that are under a certain length. This is common syntax with Django ORM queries.

Comment: @cezar This question is simple enough (how to Query for distinct model instances using values from a many to one table in Django ORM) that someone with more experience in Django should have no trouble with suggestions without running code, imho. I'm sure it's a common use case, I just don't have a much experience with Django ORM query syntax.

Comment: The line length won't be exceeded. This is what I was thinking: https://gist.github.com/cezar77/236e47f5ff361bcbbc29e1727a03b298

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

So you say:

> Get all distinct orders where the city, state, and country match and count the number of orders (bookings), their value, and their average value.

I interpret that and your query example as you're looking for all the adjustment count, total and average per city.

I'm uncertain on what amount you are trying to add: the order amount or the adjustment amount. Since I don't see how you could aggregate the order amount per location - since location is tied to the adjustment only - I will assume you are wanting the adjustment amounts.

If all my assumptions are correct you should go through the Location model. For simplicity I have omitted your filters and exclusions.

```
Location.objects.values(city)
  .annotate(
    bookings=Count('adjustments__amount'),  
    total_booking_value=Sum('adjustments__amount'), 
    average_booking_value=Avg('adjustments__amount')
  )
```

This should give you something like this:

```
{'city': 'Dallas', 'bookings': 3, 'total_booking_value': 724.0, 'average_booking_value': 241.33333333333334}, 
{'city': 'Los Angeles', 'bookings': 2, 'total_booking_value': 434.0, 'average_booking_value': 217.0}, 
{'city': 'New York', 'bookings': 3, 'total_booking_value': 745.0, 'average_booking_value': 248.33333333333334}
```

Comment: The line break in the Python code block after the first line is not correct.

Comment: It should be getting the `order.amount` value, based on the filter I'm running. Each order has 1 to many `adjustments`, each of which has a `location`. I only want 1 order to count per location, even though an order may have multiple `adjustments`. If I do what you're saying, it will give me all locations, but not the orders specific that I'm looking for. Location doesn't know anything about the orders or adjustments (as you can see from the models). A Location is just a place on earth.

Comment: So let's suppose order 1 is $1000 and has a $200 adjustment with a New York location and a $300 adjustment with a Melbourne location. What do you want your output to be?

Comment: It should never happen. The customer will use a credit card (which is where we get the zipcode data from) and generally speaking, no one has 2 different cards with 2 different locations. I haven't seen it happen yet, out of millions of transactions.

Comment: Ah ok. The model doesn't know that though. I think this is part of what's giving you trouble. So assume that location was somehow part of the order model. You would just aggregate data from the order table. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Yeah that's why this is such a difficult problem.

Comment: There's ways to do this, but really you should rethink how the location is stored. Right now different locations can be tied to an order. I understand that this doesn't happen in reality, but that's how you have your model.  That's also why it's more complicated right now. The simplest solution might be to add copy the location to the order - assuming it doesn't change ever - and then run a query from there.

Comment: Love it @PhilipBlondé! Thanks for the suggestions!